# Convert a unix file to Windows Batch file: upload table to database

Tags: unix, batch-file

I have a unix file and want to convert it to windows batch file. It's used to upload a table in .txt file to database.

```
#!/bin/sh
$HOME/.profile
dest_table=$2
file=$1
echo "$file"
  sed -e 's/^M//g' $file > __tmp
  cat __tmp > $file
  nzload -u $NZ_USER  -pw mypassword -db databasename -host $NZ_HOST -delim ','  -df "/input01/username/$file" -t $dest_table;
echo "done"
```

And the code to run this file is:

```
upload.sh t12371.txt t12371_data
```

Data in .txt file will be uploaded to t12371_data in database.

How do I convert the code to run it in Windows?
Thanks!

Comment: Wait, are you asking for a program to automatically do this? HA Yeah right

Comment: What have you tried so far? We're not here to write code for you, but we'll help you write it yourself.